# reorder list of vectors by norm

Tags: python, numpy

I have array `A` containing a list of `nvec` 3D-vectors, `A.shape==(nvec,3)`. I want to reorder rows of `A` according to the vectors' norms:

```
norm=numpy.square(A).sum(axis=1)
rank=numpy.argsort(norm)
```

I tried `A[rank,:]` but it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the second subscript:

```
A[rank]
```

Comment: Arggg, it turns out A[rank] does not work, I guess because A is not a numpy.ndarray object but an h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset object. I naively thought I could apply all kinds of numpy transformations to it. The funny thing is that numpy.square and numpy.argsort did work.

Comment: start with `A = numpy.array(A)`

Comment: Yes, A[rank] certainly works after 'casting' to a numpy.ndarray object. Thank y'all!!!